# Excel 2007: Find a cell value searching for multiple columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'd like to develop a simple function like this

Search(value, range, offset)

that given the following table

```
     A    B    C   

1    10   A    desc for 10a
2    20   B    desc for 20b
3    30   C    desc for 30c
```

would return the following

```
Search(10; a1:c3; 3) -> desc for 10a
Search(A; a1:c3; 3)  -> desc for 10a

Search(20; a1:c3; 3) -> desc for 20a
Search(B; a1:c3; 3)  -> desc for 20a
Search(desc for 20a; a1:c3; 3)  -> desc for 20a
```

That is, it should allow me to search any column in the range, not just for the first one like VLookup does

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how predictable your columns are.  If there are no distinguishing characteristics, then you'll have a tough time.  However, if you can determine from the search string which column will contain the match, then you're OK.  In your example, a numeric value would only exist in Column A, a single letter string would only exist in Column B, and longer strings would only exist in Column C.  In this case, you could use these two formulas:

Put the search value in E1.  In F1: `=IF(ISNUMBER($E1),0,IF(LEN($E1)=1,1,2))`

In G1: `=VLOOKUP($E1,OFFSET($A$1,0,$F1,10,(3-$F1)),(3-$F1),FALSE)`

You can certainly combine the two into a single formula, by replacing all the $F1's with the full formula.  I am keeping them separate here for clarity of the functionality.

Also, the 10 in the offset formula needs to correspond to the total number of rows in your lookup range.